# UPDATE Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema a la hora de hacer un `UPDATE`. Tengo que actualizar un registro que éste a su vez, pertenece a un registro de otra tabla. Me explico mejor en el ejemplo:

Tabla 1. Muestras

```
pk   |  fecha_salida
---------------------
416      NULL
417      NULL
418      NULL
```

Tabla 2. Envios

```
pk   |   envio  |  fk_muestra
------------------------------
1        1           416
2        1           417
3        2           418
```

En un `UPDATE` quiero que me actualice el campo `fecha_salida` de la `Tabla 1` solamente a los `fk_muestra` que pertenezcan al `envio = 1`.

La sentencia `UPDATE` que he intentado es la siguiente:

```
update tabla1 set fecha_salida = '2021-04-27' where pk = (select fk_muestra from tabla2 where envio = 1);
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: @BetaM Lo que intento hacer es solamente actualizar las muestras que pertenezcan al envio 1. No veo el poner LIMIT 1 porque eso solo me va a actualizar un solor registro y quiero que me actualice las 2 muestras o todas las que haya en el envio 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas haciendo una comparación de un valor de una columna con multiples valores. Para que te funcione correctamente debes usar `IN`, que comprueba que tu valor coincida con alguno de los valores devueltos por el subquery:

```
UPDATE tabla1 SET fecha_salida = '2021-04-27' WHERE pk IN (SELECT fk_muestra FROM tabla2 WHERE envio = 1);
```

Comment: Perfecto!! Eso era lo que buscaba, funcionó a la primera! Gracias